# How to remove repeating values from foreach php?

Tags: php, foreach

I have dropdwon menu items which im getting from a another file. and im getting and i want to mark selected value as well. when i trying with below code. selected value and the related foreach item both displaying in dropdwon . how to keep only one. please advice

```
        $html .= '<select>';
        $html .= '<option value="">Select</option>';
        foreach ($List as $ll) {
            if ($ll== $this->ll) {
                $html .= '<option selected value="'.$this->ll.'">width to '.$this->blockWidth.'%</option>';

            }

            $html .= '<option value="'.$ll.'"> width to '.$ll.'%</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: You must make filter down your list before passing to `foreach`

Comment: From what I see, all you need is an `else`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put the second assignment in an `else`, or refactor the common part into a single expression. I prefer the latter. Here is the refactor:

```
foreach ($List as $blockWidth) {
    $html .= '<option '.
        ($blockWidth == $this->blockWidth ? 'selected' : '').
        'value="'.$blockWidth.'"> width to '.$blockWidth.'%</option>';
}
```

Note the conditional you currently have in the `if` is now in the `$html .=` assignment in the form of a ternary expression.

Answer (score 0):

Filter your $List  before passing it to the loop !

Comment: They need an `else` is all. They are duplicating when the `if` is met...